# Responsive layout broken on certain iPhones

Tags: html, css, ios, mobile-safari

I'm experiencing a mobile responsiveness issue only on certain iPhones. The div which contains the column image as a background uses em width, and an aspect ratio to scale up or down depending on zoom level; but the proportions seem wrong on iOS and parts of the image are cut off.

I'm noticing a similar stretching issue in a different section of the app where the width and height of a radio input are both set as 1em and it appears to be stretching vertically on iOS.

I have a suspicion that Safari is doing something wacky with relative units where vertical em is larger than horizontal em but I don't really know and I don't have an iPhone so it's very hard to test.

```css
      .main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("../assets/home/background.png");
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: bottom;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding-top: 1em;
  .column-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 2;
    padding-top: 3em;
    .column {
      display: flex;
      background-image: url("../assets/home/column.png");
      background-size: cover;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      width: 15em;
      aspect-ratio: 11/15;
      padding-top: 88%;
      justify-content: center;
```

```html
<template>
  <main class="main">
    <div class="column-container column-1">
      <div class="column">
        // Some other stuff
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</template>
```

[image: Broken layout on iOS]

[image: Working layout on android]

[image: Stretched radio buttons]

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide working basic replication here (and perhaps also in an online IDE where it's easier to test responsiveness) to make it easier for people to help. Also maybe make red arrows in your screenshots pointing to the issue.

Comment: One comment, it's strange that you have two pieces of column to align horizontally. Is the bottom piece of column part of the bottom cloud (an image?).

Comment: So the column image has both the top and bottom parts of it combined but to create the 'floating in cloud' effect in the mobile layout I line it up with an extra two segments of the column base to lengthen it. I probably could/should just combine it into a single longer image so there's no alignment concerns there

Comment: on mobile browser try switching  height: 100vh to height: 100dvh that will help with the image getting cut off

Comment: Re: cloud -- Well whatever the case, ideally the cloud is an isolated image with transparency (PNG 24bit) and floating over top of the column (higher z-index).

Comment: What iOS versions are they running? Safari started supporting `aspect-ratio` just over two years ago with vestion 15.